# Summarize consecutive array items

Tags: php, arrays, date

I have an array like the following:

```
Array
(
    [10:00-18:00] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mon
            [1] => Tues
            [2] => Wed
            [4] => Fri
            [5] => Sat
        )

    [10:00-21:00] => Array
        (
            [3] => Thu
        )

    [10:00-13:00] => Array
        (
            [6] => Sun
        )

)
```

In PHP I am trying to summarize the dates such as a human would do:
ie. reduce the consecutive dates:

[10:00-18:00] Mon - Wed, Fri - Sat

Any ideas?

Comment: try the [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function

Comment: Have you attempted to write any code for creating the text `Mon - Wed`?  I am trying to think of a way to do it.... Is there a way you're trying to work it but got stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$times = [ '10:00-18:00' => [  0=>'mon', 1=>'tue', 3=>'thu', 4=>'fri', 5=>'sat'],
        '10:00-21:00' => [ 1=>'tue' , 2=>'wed', 3=> 'thu', 5=> 'sat']];


$info = array( );

foreach ( $times as $time => $days )
{
    $first_day   = false;
    $last_day    = false;
    $info[$time] = array( );
    $day_strings = array( );

    foreach ( $days as $index => $day )
    {
        if ( $last_day + 1 != $index  && $last_day !== false)
        {
            $day_strings[] = $first_day != $last_day ? "$days[$first_day] - $days[$last_day]" : $days[$first_day];
            $first_day     = false;
            $last_day      = false;
        }

        if ( $first_day === false )
            $first_day = $index;

        $last_day = $index;
    }

    if ( $last_day !== false )
        $day_strings[] = $first_day != $last_day ? "$days[$first_day] - $days[$last_day]" : $days[$first_day];

    $info[$time] = implode( ', ', $day_strings );
}
print_r( $info );
?>
```

Comment: That didn't work at all for me... I think I'm putting the array in wrong.  Can you show some sample input/output?

Answer (score 0):

notice that my input is different than yours...

```
<?php 
$times = 
      array (
        '10:00-18:00' => 
        array (
          0 => 'Mon',
          1 => 'Tues',
          2 => 'Wed',
          3 => 'Fri',
          4 => 'Sat',
        ),
        '10:00-21:00' => 
        array (
          3 => 'Thu',
        ),
        '11:00-21:00' => 
        array (
          0 => 'Tues',
          1 => 'Wed',
          2 => 'Thu',
        ),
        '10:00-13:00' => 
        array (
          0 => 'Sun',
          1 => 'Mon',
        ),
      );

$info = array(); 
foreach ($times as $time => $days)
{
   $days = process_days($days);  
   $info[] = $time.":  ".implode(', ',$days); 
}

print_r($info); 

/*
Array
(
    [0] => 10:00-18:00:  Mon - Wed, Fri - Sat
    [1] => 10:00-21:00:  
    [2] => 11:00-21:00:  Tue - Thu
    [3] => 10:00-13:00:  Sun - Mon
)
*/


function process_days($days)
{  
   $days = order_the_days($days); 

   $return = array(); 
   $end_day = end($days); 

   reset($days);  

   $consecutive = false;  
   $consecutive_days = array();  
   $current_day = key($days);     

   while ($days[$current_day] !== $end_day)
   { 
      next($days);    
      $next_day = key($days);    

      if ($next_day == $current_day+1 || ($next_day==1 && $current_day=7))
      {
         $consecutive = true;  
         $consecutive_days[] = $current_day;
      }
      else // not consecutive 
      { 
         if ($consecutive===true)
         {  
            $return[] = figure_out_consecutive_days($consecutive_days,$current_day,$days); 
            $consecutive_days = array(); 
         }
         else
         {
            $return[] = $days[$current_day];
         } 
         $consecutive = false; 
      } 

      $current_day = key($days);  
   } 
   if ($consecutive) {
      $return[] = figure_out_consecutive_days($consecutive_days,$current_day,$days);  
   }
   return $return; 
}

function figure_out_consecutive_days($consecutive_days,$current_day,$days)
{
   $consecutive_days[$current_day] = $days[$current_day];
   reset($consecutive_days);
   $first = current($consecutive_days);  
   $end   = end($consecutive_days);  
   return $days[$first]." - $end";  
}

function order_the_days($days)
{
   $return = array(); 
   foreach ($days as $i => $day)
   {
      $day = substr($day,0,3); 
      $dow = date('N', strtotime($day));
      $return[$dow] = $day;
   }
   return $return;
}

?>
```

Comment: I thought it might be easier without imploding the array to start with. The key is always going to be in consecutive order.

Comment: It's already an array, so why are you imploding it again? It's unnecessary.

Comment: @AmalMurali: huh?  It's an array of arrays.  To flatten the highest index into a string that represents that key value and the values of the array below it, you have to do something to concatenate those values.  Imploding turns something from an array into a string.  Exploding turns a string into an array.  I'm really confused at your comment.  Are you unhappy I stored the output strings in another array?  Is that it?  I'm working on the day spanning issue but I'm waiting to see if the OP has tried anything yet. It's hard and I don't want to try something that he's tried which doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah. Why are you storing the date and days in a 'string'?

Comment: because the final product is a string that represents the array...? the desired output for the first index of the array in the question is a string that equals `[10:00-18:00] Mon - Wed, Fri - Sat`.  I'm not sure what you're getting at.  The hard part is to figure out the `Mon-Wed` text for that string (instead of Mon,Tue,Wed).  See the updated code in my post.

Comment: I'm working on the day spanning issue but I'm waiting to see if the OP has tried anything first. It's hard and I don't want to try something that he's tried which doesn't work.  He just hasn't replied yet.  I'm really confused as to what makes you believe that we shouldn't end up with strings...?